# change class of div on scroll HTML5 with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is to call a function every time a person scrolls that checks the current class of container and adds +1 to the current value of the current data attribute and then toggles the class relative to the data attribute it is currently changing the class on scroll but giving a "NaN. I am already running this function on click and it works fine.

here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/kaL63/1/

This is my function on scroll

```
var timeout;

$(window).scroll(function() {
if(typeof timeout == "number") {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    delete timeout;
}
  timeout = window.setTimeout( check, 100);
});
```

My html Looks like this

```
<div class="container year-1987" data-year-index="1987">
    Some Content
</div>
```

the function I am calling right now that I think should work..

```
function check(){
                var
            animationHolder = $('.container'),
            currentClass = animationHolder.attr("class").match(/year[\w-]*\b/);
               var goToYear = $('.container').data('year-index');
               var goToYear2 = parseInt(goToYear,1000) + 1;

               animationHolder.toggleClass(currentClass + ' year-' + goToYear2);
               animationHolder.attr('data-year-index', goToYear2);
            }
```

My working code on click

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var
            animationHolder = $('.container'),
            currentClass = animationHolder.attr("class").match(/year[\w-]*\b/);
        var goToYear = $(this).data('year-index');
        animationHolder.toggleClass(currentClass + ' year-' + goToYear);
        animationHolder.attr('data-year-index', goToYear);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your `check` method:

```
function check() {
    var $container  = $('.container'),
        currentYear = $container.data('m-index'),
        nextYear    = 1 + currentYear;
    $container.removeClass('m-' + currentYear).addClass('m-' + nextYear);
    $container.data('m-index', nextYear);
}
```

I made the following changes:

- There is no need for the regular expression since we can generate the class name ourselves.
- I am not sure why you were originally using two separate data-attributes (m-index and year-index), but I switched them to both match.  If you need both of them, some more logic is needed to use `year-index` after the initial call.
- I am now updating `m-index` via `.data()` rather than setting a data attribute.

This method seemed to work fine for me.